# Scilab: How to do short time fourier transform of audio signal?

Tags: signal-processing, fft, scilab

I have signal (s) that looks like this:
[signal [s, Fs] = wavread([file])](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpwxa.jpg)

It represents 2 separate sounds, so I want to do short time Fourier transform (STFT) using `Ctfrstft()`, but not for the whole signal.

I have to do STFT for cropped signal, so I want to use something like this:

```
signal = [s(13000:25000) s(36000:45000)]
```

Scilab plots this `signal`, but my code for STFT doesn`t work:

```
time = (0:lenght(s)-1)./Fs; 
[stft,T,F]=Ctfrstft(signal);
mesh(time,F*100,abs(stft));
```

I get either error`mem_alloc_tfr : memory allocation`  for Ctfrstft or scilab crashes and reboots.

Comment: Try to reinstall Scilab and choose  "reference" FFTW3 library instead of "intel math kernel".

Comment: My version is the "reference" one

Comment: Can you confirm that the signal given to Ctfrstft() has length 21002 (that's what I concluded from your first line of code above) ? I just tested Ctfrstft() with a signal of that length and it freezed my Scilab 6.1.1. I think that Ctfrstft() just cannot handle a signal of that length. Please report this on the module page at https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/stftb